# Zeppelin livy.sparkr interpreter failed with multiple line script

Tags: r, apache-zeppelin, livy

In my zeppelin (0.7.3) livy2.sparkr interpreter, scripts that more than 1 line couldn't work.
[image]

Then I tried this in R:

```
> parse(text="hello<-function(name){\r\n    sprintf(\"Hello %s\", name);}")
```

> Error in parse(text = "hello<-function(name){\r\n    sprintf(\"Hello
>   %s\", name);}") :    :1:23: unexpected input 1:
>   hello<-function(name){
>                             ^

```
> parse(text="hello<-function(name){\n    sprintf(\"Hello %s\", name);}")
```

> expression(hello<-function(name){
>       sprintf("Hello %s", name);})
>   >

Seems zeppelin interpreter mistreat the line ending to Windows style, and R doesn't support \r.

Anyone met this issue?